# How to get an average of marks in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and can't figure this project out. Can someone help me out?

```
    System.out.println (" \nEnter your hybrid activity mark out of 5: ") ;
    mark1 = scan.nextInt() ;

    System.out.println (" Enter your lab mark out of 10: ") ;
    mark2 = scan.nextInt() ;

    System.out.println (" Enter your assignment mark out of 100: ") ;
    mark3 = scan.nextInt() ;

    System.out.println (" Enter your test(s)/quiz mark out of 25: ") ;
    mark4 = scan.nextInt();      

    System.out.println (" Enter your lab test mark out of 5: ") ;
    mark5 = scan.nextInt() ;

    System.out.println (" Enter your final exam mark out of 30: ") ;
    mark6 = scan.nextInt() ;


   average = (float)  (mark1/5*100 + mark2/10*100 + mark3/100*100 + mark4/25*100 + mark5/5*100 + mark6/30*100)/6;
   System.out.println(" Calculated final mark is " + average);
```

When I enter the data in with a 100% for every mark the program gives me a 100% but when I enter anything different I get 0 % I'll put that example further down

Enter your hybrid activity mark out of 5:

```
5
 Enter your lab mark out of 10: 
10
 Enter your assignment mark out of 100: 
100
 Enter your test(s)/quiz mark out of 25: 
25
 Enter your lab test mark out of 5: 
5
 Enter your final exam mark out of 30: 
30
 Calculated final mark is 100.0
```

Example #2

```
Enter your hybrid activity mark out of 5: 
4
 Enter your lab mark out of 10: 
8
 Enter your assignment mark out of 100: 
95
 Enter your test(s)/quiz mark out of 25: 
23
 Enter your lab test mark out of 5: 
4
 Enter your final exam mark out of 30: 
28
 Calculated final mark is 0.0
```

I really need help i cant figure it out this is my last hope

Comment: Integer math. Promote one of the terms to a `double`.

Comment: replace float with double

Comment: You're a life saver. Thanks Elliott

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
float average = (2/5f*100 + 5/10f*100 + 50/100f*100 + 12/25f*100 + 2/5f*100 + 15/30f*100) / 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Integer math, make your mark variables (mark1, mark2, etc) doubles instead of ints.

Answer (score 0):

If using Java 8 try streaming the numbers and utilize IntStream.average ()

Answer (score 0):

your complete solution with output,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        float mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5, mark6;
        double average;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println (" \nEnter your hybrid activity mark out of 5: ") ;
        mark1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println (" Enter your lab mark out of 10: ") ;
        mark2 = scan.nextInt() ;

        System.out.println (" Enter your assignment mark out of 100: ") ;
        mark3 = scan.nextInt() ;

        System.out.println (" Enter your test(s)/quiz mark out of 25: ") ;
        mark4 = scan.nextInt();      

        System.out.println (" Enter your lab test mark out of 5: ") ;
        mark5 = scan.nextInt() ;

        System.out.println (" Enter your final exam mark out of 30: ") ;
        mark6 = scan.nextInt() ;

        average =  (mark1/5*100 + mark2/10*100 + mark3/100*100 + mark4/25*100 + mark5/5*100 + mark6/30*100)/6;
        System.out.println(" Calculated final mark is " + average);
    }
```

**Out-put :**

```
Enter your hybrid activity mark out of 5: 
5
 Enter your lab mark out of 10: 
10
 Enter your assignment mark out of 100: 
100
 Enter your test(s)/quiz mark out of 25: 
25
 Enter your lab test mark out of 5: 
5
 Enter your final exam mark out of 30: 
30
 Calculated final mark is 100.0
```

*Second time with different input,*

```
Enter your hybrid activity mark out of 5: 
4
 Enter your lab mark out of 10: 
8
 Enter your assignment mark out of 100: 
95
 Enter your test(s)/quiz mark out of 25: 
23
 Enter your lab test mark out of 5: 
4
 Enter your final exam mark out of 30: 
28
 Calculated final mark is 86.72222137451172
```